# How to make nfsv4 ID mapping work between macOS Big Sur client and Ubuntu 20.04 server 2021

Tags: ubuntu, macos, nfsv4

**Can nfsv4 ID mapping work between macOS and Linux without an Open Directory server?**

1. nfs version is 4, all versions 1…3 are disabled
2. Kerberos is MIT
3. Share sec is krb5p
4. The realm is REALM.COM and nfs and kdc servers and macOS clients have domain realm.com

macOS

```
/etc/nfs.conf:
nfs.client.default_nfs4domain = realm.com
hostname
mac.realm.com
/etc/hosts:
1.2.3.4 server.realm.com
```

Linux:

```
cat /proc/fs/nfsd/versions
-2 -3 +4 +4.1 +4.2
cat /sys/module/nfsd/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping
N
/etc/idmapd.conf:
[General]
Verbosity = 3
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
[Mapping]
Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup
hostname --fqdn
server.realm.com
/etc/hosts:
127.0.1.1 server.realm.com server
```

The mac has user:group:

- root:wheel
- admuser:staff
- nobody:nobody

— wheel and staff are generic BSD groups

Linux has user.group:

- root.root
- admuser.admuser
- nobody.nogroup

On macOS, admuser:staff executes the mount command:

```
mount -tnfs -overs=4,proto=tcp,port=2049,sec=krb5p server.realm.com:/files ~/files
```

**Current State**

In the current nfs client and server configuration, it’s all nobody.nogroup and nobody:nobody

```
tail --follow=name --retry /var/log/syslog | egrep '^.{16}[^ ]* rpc.idmapd[[]'
Feb 16 10:17:11 server rpc.idmapd[3981346]: nfsdcb: authbuf=gss/krb5p authtype=user
Feb 16 10:17:11 server rpc.idmapd[3981346]: Server : (user) id "0" -> name "root@localdomain"
Feb 16 10:17:11 server rpc.idmapd[3981346]: nfsdcb: authbuf=gss/krb5p authtype=group
Feb 16 10:17:11 server rpc.idmapd[3981346]: Server : (group) id "0" -> name "root@localdomain"
Feb 16 10:17:19 server rpc.idmapd[3981346]: nfsdcb: authbuf=gss/krb5p authtype=user
Feb 16 10:17:19 server rpc.idmapd[3981346]: Server : (user) id "65534" -> name "nobody@localdomain"
Feb 16 10:17:19 server rpc.idmapd[3981346]: nfsdcb: authbuf=gss/krb5p authtype=group
Feb 16 10:17:19 server rpc.idmapd[3981346]: Server : (group) id "65534" -> name "nogroup@localdomain"
```

The first pair is mount, second pair is access

macOS:

```
nfs4mapid admuser
user admuser maps to id 501
        mapping done through guid 126DA715-EAD2-48BB-9A40-653AED2D78CD
nfs4mapid -u501
user id 501 maps to admuser@realm.com
        mapping done through guid 126DA715-EAD2-48BB-9A40-653AED2D78CD
nfs4mapid -G staff
group staff maps to id 20
        mapping done through guid ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000014
nfs4mapid -g20
group id 20 maps to staff@realm.com
        mapping done through guid ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000014
nfs4mapid root
user root maps to id 0
        mapping done through guid FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000
nfs4mapid -u0
user id 0 maps to root@realm.com
        mapping done through guid FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000
nfs4mapid -G wheel
group wheel maps to id 0
        mapping done through guid ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000000
nfs4mapid -g0
group id 0 maps to wheel@realm.com
        mapping done through guid ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000000
```

- Linux max version is 4.2
- macOS max version is 4.0

**Desired Mappings**

When doing ls -l on the macOS client:

- Linux user root -> macOS user root
- Linux group root -> macOS group wheel
- Linux user admuser -> macOS user admuser
- Linux group admuser -> macOS group staff

When creating a file on the server from macOS

- macOS user root -> Linux user root
- macOS group wheel -> Linux group root
- macOS user admuser -> Linux user admuser
- macOS group staff -> Linux group admuser

**Can nfsv4 ID mapping work between macOS and Linux without an Open Directory server?**

If Open Directory is required, how is that done?

Comment: I think 127.0.0.1 in the /etc/hosts on Linux side is incorrect. Keep 127.0.0.1 as localhost and FQDN as normal IP address

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost. 127.0.1.1 is fqdn and short hostname. That’s how it’s done in Ubuntu 20.04. In this implementation it is simplified to avoid using dhcp and dns

Comment: Ah I see @Keith